Trigger useEffect on second pathname change
I want to scroll down below the hero block when a user changes the page. I have this code so far in my App.jsx:
const { pathname } = useLocation()
 const paragraphRef = useRef(null)
 useEffect(() => {
    window.scroll({
      top: paragraphRef.current.offsetTop,
      behavior: "smooth",
      block: "start"
    })
  }, [pathname])

The problem is that I want the Hero block visible on the first visit and trigger the scrolldown afterwards on every page.

You can use a state variable to track whether the user has visited the page before:
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  const paragraphRef = useRef(null);
  const [hasVisited, setHasVisited] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (hasVisited && paragraphRef.current) {
      window.scroll({
        top: paragraphRef.current.offsetTop,
        behavior: "smooth",
        block: "start",
      });
    } else {
      setHasVisited(true);
    }
  }, [pathname, hasVisited]);


Explanation:
State Variable (hasVisited): Tracks whether the user has visited the page before. Initially, it is false, which prevents the scroll action on the first visit.

